# Java commons cli parser not recognizing command line arguments

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons-cli

This should be very simple but I am not sure why its not working. I am trying pass arguments with a name (So I can pass arguments in any order) using the apache commons CLI library but It seems to be not working. I want to pass the arguments from eclipse IDE. I know this part is not the problem because I am able to print the arguments with args[0] kind.

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption("d", false, "add two numbers");
    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args);
    if(cmd.hasOption("d")) {
        System.out.println("found d");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found");
    }
}
```

The above lines are exactly like the examples given online but i dont know why its not working. I am struggling this from a day now. Please help where I am going wrong.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(args[0]);` this print?

Comment: I am passing the arguments like ${d} in eclipse and this variable has 15 in it, so it prints 15

Comment: I think that option `d` means that you should pass `-d` on command line. If you want to pass 15 for `d` parameter, then use `-d 15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [examples](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html) name of the parameter should be present in command line

**Property without value**

```
Usage: ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
-a, --all                  do not hide entries starting with .
```

And the respective code is:

```
// create the command line parser
CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();

// create the Options
Options options = new Options();
options.addOption( "a", "all", false, "do not hide entries starting with ." );
```

In this scenario correct call is:

`ls -a` or `ls --all`

**With value separated by space**

```
-logfile <file>        use given file for log
```

Respective code is:

```
Option logfile   = OptionBuilder.withArgName( "file" )
                                .hasArg()
                                .withDescription(  "use given file for log" )
                                .create( "logfile" );
```

And call would be:

```
app -logfile name.of.file.txt
```

**With value separated by equals**

```
-D<property>=<value>   use value for given property
```

The code is:

```
Option property  = OptionBuilder.withArgName( "property=value" )
                                .hasArgs(2)
                                .withValueSeparator()
                                .withDescription( "use value for given property" )
                                .create( "D" );
```

And call would be:

```
app -Dmyprop=myvalue
```